Remove offline Server (Front-end) from SharePoint 2016 Farm
In my farm there are old servers that have been turned off for a long time and are not accessible.
My admin center is crashed after install sts2016-kb5002583-fullfile-x64-glb (Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'.). I want to try to restore it by running sharepoint configuration wizard. But because of the old servers I can’t launch wizard.
so can i deleted old offline servers?
Thank

The best practice to remove a server from a SharePoint farm is directly from this server, by uninstalling SharePoint and using the PowerShell command Disconnect-SPConfigurationDatabase locally.
Of course, it's not possible if the server is offline. But there is another solution, by using SharePoint Central Administration (if you can access it):
To remove a server from a SharePoint farm by using Central Administration

Verify that the user account that completes this procedure has the following credentials:


The user account that performs this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
The user account that performs this procedure is a member of the Administrators group on the server.


On the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the System Settings section, click Manage servers in this farm.

On the Servers in Farm page, locate the row that contains the name of the server that you want to remove, and then click Remove Server.

In the warning that appears, click OK to remove the server or click Cancel to stop the operation. The page updates, and the server that you removed no longer appears in the list of servers.


Source: Remove a server from a farm in SharePoint Servers 2016, 2019, and Subscription Edition
